# struct is incompatible with parameter of type "long long"

Tags: c, function

I have here a simple phone book application written in C for a lab assignment. I am having trouble however, it does not compile - I receive the error "struct PhoneBook_Contacts" is incompatible with parameter of type "long long". I am unsure how to change or fix this, I am a complete beginner with C. The error is on line 37. Please let me know if you can help. I know what the error is, just not how to fix it. If you could please let me know exactly what to change on what line :D

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

void decompose(long long phone_number, int *area, int *prefix, int *lineno);

void decompose(long long phone_number, int *area, int *prefix, int *lineno) {
    *area = (int)(phone_number / (10000000));
    *prefix = (int)((phone_number % (10000000) / 10000));
    *lineno = (int)(phone_number % (10000));
}


struct PhoneBook_Contacts
{
    char FirstName[20]; //Entered First Name
    char LastName[20]; //Entered Last Name
    char PhoneNumber[20]; //Phone Number
}; //TypeDef to Modify structure name



   //Begin main function
int main(void)
{
    int area, prefix, lineno;
    int counter = 0; 
    int iSelection = 0; //Variable to use to select menu choice//Global counter variable used to keep track of number of contacts
                     //phone *phonebook; //Phonebook instance
                     //phonebook = (phone*)malloc(sizeof(phone) * 1); //Allocate memory for contacts
    struct PhoneBook_Contacts phonebook[3];



    printf("---=== Phone Numbers ===---\n\n");


    while (iSelection <= 4)
    {

        printf("1. Display Phone List\n");
        printf("2. Add a Number\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &iSelection);
        printf("\n");

        // Add Friend
        if (iSelection == 2)
        {
            if (counter == 3) {
                printf("ERROR!!! Phone Number List is Full\n");
                printf("\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("Add a Number\n");
                printf("============\n");
                scanf("%s", phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
                printf("\n");
                counter++;
            }
        } //End if
          //printf("%d\n", iSelection);
          //Print Phonebook Entries
        if (iSelection == 1)
        {
            int x = 0;
            printf("Phone Numbers\n");
            printf("==============\n");
            for (x = 0; x < counter; x++) //For loop to print entries
            {
                decompose(phonebook[x], &area, &prefix, &lineno);
                printf("%s\n", phonebook[x].PhoneNumber); //Contact's Phone Number
                printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
                printf("\n");
            }
            //printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
            //printf("\n");

            //End for loop
        } //End if

          //Exit Application
        if (iSelection == 0)
        {
            printf("Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!\n");
            break;
        } //End if

    } //End while
    return 0;
} //End main function
```

Comment: The first argument to `decompose()` is supposed to be a `phone_number`, but you call it as `decompose(phonebook[x], &area, &prefix, &lineno)`. `phonebook[x]` is a `Phonebook_Contacts` structure, how is it supposed to decompose that?

Comment: It's those pesky compiler messages again. If they only told you what the problem was and where it occurred. Oh wait....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compile baby. Compile... and solve one problem... when print data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

struct PhoneBook_Contacts
{
    char FirstName[20]; //Entered First Name
    char LastName[20]; //Entered Last Name
  long unsigned PhoneNumber[20]; //Phone Number
}; //TypeDef to Modify structure name

void decompose(long unsigned number, int* area, int* prefix, int* lineno) {
  *area = (number / (10000000));
  *prefix = ((number % (10000000) / 10000));
  *lineno = (number % (10000));
}

//Begin main function
int main(void)
{
    int area, prefix, lineno;
    int counter = 0; 
    int iSelection = 0; //Variable to use to select menu choice//Global counter variable used to keep track of number of contacts
                     //phone *phonebook; //Phonebook instance
                     //phonebook = (phone*)malloc(sizeof(phone) * 1); //Allocate memory for contacts
    struct PhoneBook_Contacts phonebook[3];



    printf("---=== Phone Numbers ===---\n\n");


    while (iSelection <= 4)
    {

        printf("1. Display Phone List\n");
        printf("2. Add a Number\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &iSelection);
        printf("\n");

        // Add Friend
        if (iSelection == 2)
        {
            if (counter == 3) {
                printf("ERROR!!! Phone Number List is Full\n");
                printf("\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("Add a Number\n");
                printf("============\n");
                scanf("%lu", phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
                printf("\n");
                counter++;
            }
        } //End if
          //printf("%d\n", iSelection);
          //Print Phonebook Entries
        if (iSelection == 1)
        {
            int x = 0;
            printf("Phone Numbers\n");
            printf("==============\n");
            for (x = 0; x < counter; x++) //For loop to print entries
            {
          decompose(*phonebook[x].PhoneNumber, &area, &prefix, &lineno);
                printf("%lu\n", *phonebook[x].PhoneNumber); //Contact's Phone Number
                printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
                printf("\n");
            }
            //printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
            //printf("\n");

            //End for loop
        } //End if

          //Exit Application
        if (iSelection == 0)
        {
            printf("Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!\n");
            break;
        } //End if

    } //End while
    return 0;
} //End main function
```

Comment: Don't post multiple answers like this. You can however, add this code to the other answer you posted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post!! It compiles now! But it seems the phone number entered does not match the one displayed when the user selects to view the phonebook. Also...it isn't formatting correctly into (123)-456-7890 format...any idea how I can solve this? or should I make a whole new topic for this question?

Comment: You want this output? Phone Numbers
==============
1234567890
(123)-456-7890

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter's type is long long

```
void decompose(long long phone_number, int *area, int *prefix, int *lineno)
```

This isn't a long long, is a struct PhoneBook_Contacts

```
struct PhoneBook_Contacts phonebook[3];
```

So You can't use phonebook like parameter.

```
decompose(phonebook[x], &area, &prefix, &lineno);
```

but this it's fine.

```
void decompose(struct PhoneBook_Contacts phone_number, int* area, int* prefix, int* lineno)
```

Also you have a problem with the division. 1st because you need use `phone_number.PhoneNumber` 2nd because `PhoneNumber` is char and not int, and 3rd... That's for you...